# What is responsible for large ppm shifts in HNMR analysis of paramagnetic compounds?

Tags: electromagnetism, atoms, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

In H-NMR spectra of paramagnetic metal acetylacetonate compounds M(III)(acac)3, large ppm shifts are observed. This is seen with other organometallic compounds as well. What is the origin of this phenomenon? How do the SOMOs interact with other MOs and nuclei of nearby atoms to affect shielding?

Comment: Consider to spell out acronyms.

Answer (score 0):

Think of every nearby magnetic nuclei and unpaired electron as a little magnet which can add to or subtract from the lab magnetic field felt by the nuclear spin in question.

The magnitude of these magnetic fields are related to the magnetic moment of the spins generating them. An unpaired electron has roughly 1000 times the magnetic moment of a neighboring hydrogen and therefore would shift your nuclear resonance significantly more.